# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, axios

I'm using **vue js**.

I retrieve an object from an **axios post call** in the **created()** method.
But when i want to render a property of this object i get :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of null"
```

On the template part i show the value of the property of the object with

```
{{ my_object['property_name'] }}
```

I have tried using **async await** and my axios call.
I also tried to put my axios call in the **beforeCreate()** method
but it didn't change anything.

Does someone know where the problem can be?

ps: Also i can give further information if needed

Comment: How do you render that itme?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim On the template part i show the value of the property of the object with 

    {{ my_object['property_name'] }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property at initial rendering is not available, so you should check its availability using conditional rendering :

```
<div v-if="my_object">
   {{ my_object['property_name'] }}
</div>
```